# Where does Notepad++ maintain its list of currently opened files?

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ on my Windows machine and by mistake I opened a 64MB file. Now my Notepad++ is stuck permanently and I am not able to use it.

Is there any configuration file which Notepad++ uses to maintain the list of opened files? If yes, then can I open that file and remove the entry of the 64MB file which I have opened in it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml

Comment: Didn't - quite - work for me. I run the Session Manager plugin, and I also had to edit it's logs via `C:\Users\SilkAndSlug\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\Config\SessionMgr\sessions`. I deleted everything within the <maintag> block, and that fixed it.

Comment: It's worth noting you can get to the appdata folder quickly by entering `%Appdata%` in Windows Explorer

Comment: Me, having same issue as OP : *"Perfect!"*  (right-click -> Edit with Notepad++... **derp!**)

Answer (score 10):

**if your notepad++ have been installed.**

there must be in :

%appdata%\Notepad++\session.xml

> %appdata% means by default:
>
> - if you're using windows 7
>     `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming`
> - if you're using windows xp or older version)
>     `C:\Documents and Settings\{username}\Application Data`

---

**if your notepad++ is portable**

there must be in :

your notepad++ programs folder.

---

the file for notepad++ portable or notepad++ installed is same:

`session.xml`

Answer (score 3):

One more thing to add here. The Old Session.xml file would have links to all the files that were open there (File Paths). They should match for the New PC. The User Name, Program Files folder (32bit or 64bit) etc should be the same. Else Notepad++ will open a blank session.

Answer (score 2):

This article helped me figure out how to move/copy my unsaved open tabs to another PC.

Install notepad++ first if not already.

Make sure notepad++ is not open/running on new PC.

On the old PC copy the backup folder located C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ to the new one (location may vary on OS).  Also copy the session.xml file.

Open notepad++ and all the open unsaved tabs should appear with content.

Comment: In 2021, I was pleased to find my unsaved tabs in:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\Backup

Comment: In addition to @PaulMcGee, this folder will only appear after you close Notepad++ with an unsaved tab that has content in it. Then the folder is created and the first file is added.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find out directly from Notepad++ and change where it stores this vital information.  As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617349/notepad-cached-files-location#29635535) look in Settings > Preferences > Backup: Backup path.  There are also other useful settings such as backup frequency.

You can also find session.xml which shows information on the temporary, unsaved files in its parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, open `notepad++.exe` with the `-nosession` [command line argument](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

### Notepad++ active tabs

##### Command line argument -approach

Start the program with the `-nosession` command line argument to avoid using the **session.xml** file for resuming the previously open tabs.

```
WIN + R > Open: "notepad++ -nosession"
```

[image: Screenshot of the Windows "Run" window opened by key-combination WIN+R with the command (notepad++ -nosession) for opening the Notepad++ in -nosession mode.]

*(Instructions on doing this through the shortcut properties under the "Portable" -section.)*

##### Notepad++ Installed

In the current installed version (v8.6) the values for the active tabs from the last session would be in:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\session.xml
```

[File history can be found in
`%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml` (though for closed files), as well as the setting to turn off the feature of resuming where you left off when starting the program: `<GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">yes</GUIConfig>` - change to `>no<`. (Settings > Preferences > Backup > "Remember current session for next launch")]

(Typically expanding to *`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`*)

---

##### Notepad++ Portable

For the **Notepad++ portable** -version, you'll need to navigate to it's application folder, and look for the **session.xml** there (alternatively you might want to check the *config.xml* that's also found there, to adjust the "RememberLastSession" setting's value).

You can find the location usually by examining your application *shortcut* for the Notepad++ that you use (possibly search for "Notepad++" from the Windows search bar - `WIN + S`) by **right clicking** it (and choosing the "Open file location", and if transferred to the Start menu's folder, right clicking the shortcut again and choosing the same "Open file location") or the program icon of the *Notepad++* in your *taskbar*, (optionally right clicking again within the context menu on the "Notepad++" that's right above the "Pin to taskbar",) and choosing "**Properties**" and there "**Open File Location**". (Or copying the path from either the "Target" or "Start in" to your File Explorer's navigation bar. The properties of the shortcut is also where you can add the command line argument to the "Target" field if needed - after the parenthesis after a space: `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -nosession`)

If your session isn't crashing immediately, you can also find the folder through the Notepad++ itself, from the

```
? > Debug Info... > "Path : C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

---

##### Note on Plugins

Some plugins you are using might interfere with the default settings of the Notepad++ and the above measures might prove insufficient for you.
For the "**Session Manager**" plugin, check it's sessions (or the config .ini file):

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\plugins\config\SessionMgr\sessions
```

AutoSave plugin or the native the backup feature might have also created copies of the large files in your backup folder:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\backup
```

---

##### Notepad++ in-app preferences

To turn off session resumption from the GUI:

```
Settings > Preferences > Backup > "Remember current session for next launch"
```

To manage the -nosession settings:

```
Settings > Preferences > "Multi-Instance & Date" > "Panel State and [-nosession]"
```

To adjust the Recent Files History:

```
Settings > Preferences > "Recent File History""
```

---

#### Official documentation

https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/session/