# Notepad++ cached files location

Tags: caching, filesystems, notepad++

On the most recent versions of Notepad++, when the application is closed, unsaved files are maintained when the application is restarted.

I presume that those files are cached on a temporary files. What is the location of that file(s).

Thank you

Answer (score 282, accepted):

I noticed it myself, and found the files inside the **backup** folder. You can check where it is using **Menu:Settings -> Preferences -> Backup**. Note : My NPP installation is portable, and on Windows, so YMMV.

Comment: NPP crashed and wiped an entire file.. and the copy on disk too! I thought I'd lost it. But the backup was there. Thank you SO much :)

Comment: Indeed a life saver. In the recent update this option got reset and I was missing like hell. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Location is same even with the non-portable MSI install. Life saver in case you need the **timestamp for last update** to a collection of notes

Comment: If you use the version from Microsoft Store, the location would be something like "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\NightRise.NotepadWrapped_bahp16nyyek9m\LocalCache\Roaming\Notepad++\backup". I almost gave up, when I luckily found this folder when I searched for "Notepad" in my Users folder.

Answer (score 145):

I lost somehow my temporary notepad++ files, they weren't showing in tabs. So I did some search in appdata folder, and I found all my temporary files there. It seems that they are stored there for a long time.

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup
```

or

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\backup
```

Comment: After Notepad++ crashed and I restarted Notepad++, a large file I'd been working was empty. Thank you very much for your post which enabled me to locate today's version of that complete file in AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work every time. I don't know how, but I managed, to lose all my temporary files of the last two weeks. I have a feeling, that it has to do something with the computer updates of our company, which is strange just because I installed the Notepad++ myself.

Comment: I had files dating back to 2 years in there!! I found this article after loosing all my "unsaved" documents! Yes, I am probably retarded to use notepad++ like this but it is truly my notepad and everything I don't even need to save in files go in there. This saved me and now I have added this folder to my daily backup! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered that NotePad++ now also creates a subfolder at the file location, called nppBackup. So if your file lived in a folder called **c:/thisfolder** have a look to see if there's a folder called **c:/thisfolder/nppBackup**.

Occasionally I couldn't find the backup in AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup, but I found it in nppBackup.