# How to get Notepad file saved location

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, notepad, win32-process

How to retrieve the actual path  of the notepad file if it is saved in drive. For example a notepad process is running and it is saved somewhere in the drive. How can I retrieve its full path? Using below code I can get the process detail, but not the actual path of particular files.

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (Process p in localByName)
    {
      string path  =  p.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
    }
```

this returns executeable path but i need Drive location whre the actual file reside.

Comment: When you say notepad file do you mean a .txt file? Or do you mean just any file that is currently open in an instance of notepad?

Comment: any file which is open in notepad.

Comment: You know you can open Notepad without a file?

Comment: my scenario is , a notepad file is running  and i will get its detail,I will close it. and populate the same file  again .

Comment: You should not do that.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: right now my aim is to get the saved location of each file which currently running. so if i want the same files, i can regenerate them on one call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", "notepad.exe");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
        {
            string CommandLine = retObject["CommandLine"].ToString();
            string path = CommandLine.Substring(CommandLine.IndexOf(" ") + 1, CommandLine.Length - CommandLine.IndexOf(" ") - 1);
        }
```

It will work only if the file is opened by double click or through command line.

Don't forget to add reference to `System.Management` by right Click on Project, Add References then select the Assemblies Tab and Search for System.Management.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: i'm unable to add reference for ManagementObjectSearcher

Comment: @navi the answer is edited to add pictures to show you how to add reference to 'System.Management'

Comment: You will also need to add this line at usings (the top of your code) "using System.Management;"

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has a session.xml file in it's %APPDATA% folder found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873184/1751481).

You can use XDocument or XPath to parse this file and retrieve the file paths. Here's how you get them with XPath:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml");

XmlNodeList files = doc.SelectNodes("//NotepadPlus/Session/mainView/File");
foreach (XmlNode file in files)
{
  Console.WriteLine(file.Attributes["filename"].Value);
}
```

Please note that notepad++ needs to be closed then re-opened to refresh this file.

Comment: The question is about Windows Notepad not Notepad++

Comment: Whoops. I never use regular Notepad, so I have always associated Notepad++ as Notepad. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

[Xenon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933272/3063835) is definitely the best if you didn't open the file via File-> Open in notepad. For fun, I tried to create a solution that will work in all cases. You can achieve this with a combination of [Microsoft TestApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestApi/) and UIAutomation. Basically I'm opening the Save As... dialog to get the file path of the currently opened file. It's ugly but it works! Note: Intall the Microsoft.TestApi nuget package, and add references to WindowsBase, System.Drawing, UIAutomationClient, and UIAutomationTypes.

```
using Microsoft.Test.Input;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        foreach (Process p in localByName)
        {
            string fileName = p.MainWindowTitle; // get file name from notepad title
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            AutomationElement windowAutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);

            var menuElements = windowAutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem));
            AutomationElement fileMenuElement = null;
            foreach (AutomationElement element in menuElements)
            {
                if (element.Current.Name == "File")
                {
                    fileMenuElement = element;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (fileMenuElement != null)
            {
                fileMenuElement.SetFocus();
                fileMenuElement.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(800); // Sleeping an arbitrary amount here since we must wait for the file menu to appear before the next line can find the menuItems. A better way to handle it is probably to run the FindAll in the next line in a loop that breaks when menuElements is no longer null.
                menuElements = fileMenuElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem));
                var saveAsMenuElement = fileMenuElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Save As..."));


                if (saveAsMenuElement != null)
                {
                    saveAsMenuElement.SetFocus();
                    saveAsMenuElement.Click();
                    Thread.Sleep(800);
                    var saveAsWindow = windowAutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));
                    var toolbarElements = saveAsWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ToolBar));

                    foreach (AutomationElement element in toolbarElements)
                        if (element.Current.Name.StartsWith("Address:"))
                            Console.WriteLine(element.Current.Name + @"\" + fileName); // Parse out the file name from this concatenation here!
                    var closeButtonElement = saveAsWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Close"));
                    closeButtonElement.Click();
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class AutomationElementExtensions
{
    public static void MoveTo(this AutomationElement automationElement)
    {
        Point somePoint;
        if (automationElement.TryGetClickablePoint(out somePoint))
            Mouse.MoveTo(new System.Drawing.Point((int)somePoint.X, (int)somePoint.Y));
    }
    public static void Click(this AutomationElement automationElement)
    {
        automationElement.MoveTo();
        Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left);
    }
}
}
```