# How to get Microsoft Word file saved location

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

How to retrieve the actual path of the All Microsoft word files if it is saved in drive. For example I have multiple ms word processes  running and these are saved somewhere in the drive. How can I retrieve full path? eg "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\testnotpad.docx" Using below code I can get the notepad process detail, but the same code with little changes "WINWORD.exe" is not working for ms word.

```
   string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", "notepad.exe");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
    {
        string CommandLine = retObject["CommandLine"].ToString();
        string path = CommandLine.Substring(CommandLine.IndexOf(" ") + 1, CommandLine.Length - CommandLine.IndexOf(" ") - 1);
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this that way.  Instead, you need to use Word automation.

Comment: @SLaks any example code? using this  Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName i can only get active window detail

Comment: Activeworkbook is Excel.....try ActiveDocument.FullName

Comment: it will return me the Active Document detail not All documents detail.. I need All opened files information

Comment: @navi: Did you look at the `Documents` collection?

Comment: And BTW, your technique won't work with Notepad either.  Just try File, Open.

Comment: Exactly what is not working for ms word? Have you tried looking at what the "CommandLine" string is using the debugger?

Comment: Nop, actualy i'm new in C# i dont have much idea

Comment: use Application.Documents and loop through the collection to get the FullName for each opened document.

Comment: @SLaks: OP has already had this explained to him in his previous question on how to do this for notepad : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932301/how-to-get-notepad-file-saved-location

Comment: @Slaks i'm doing a task for All kind of files so now i'm working on ms office files.. as i wrote i'm new in C#

Comment: @PaulF: Yes; that answer is wrong.  This isn't actually possible for arbitrary programs.

Comment: @PaulF I've checked through debuger. CommandLine doesn't contain file path information